# page in Firefox and chrome not displaying the ul correctly

Tags: php, html, css

I made changes to a page [www.redsandsafaris.com](http://redsandsafaris.com) and after the changes the right sidebar is not showing the images from the css style sheet. if you navigate to the german translation, [redsandsafaris.de](http://www.redsandsafaris.de) it uses the exact same information and it is working properly. It displays perfectly in IE and safari, but not in Chrome and Firefox. What am I missing here!

```
<div id="mainrcolIndex">
  <ul>
    <li class="profmain_location">
      <a href="pages/profileMain.html"
         alt="Hunting farms and hunting areas"
         title="Here are your hunting farms and hunting areas in Namibia">
        Hunting Guides & Farms
      </a>
    </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

'

```
#mainrcolIndex ul { list-style-type: none; } 
#mainrcolIndex ul li { } 
#mainrcolIndex ul a { 
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
} 

li.profmain_location a { 
  height: 45px; 
  width: 240px; 
  float: left; 
  background-image: url(../images/profmain_location.jpg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: right; 
  text-indent: -3000px; 
} 

li.profmain_location:hover a { 
  float: left; 
  height: 45px; 
  width: 240px; 
  background-image: url(../images/profmain_location.jpg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: left; 
}
```

Comment: Add code to the question rather than linking

Comment: `<div id="mainrcolIndex"> 
     <ul>
        <li class="profmain_location"><a href="pages/profileMain.html" alt="Hunting farms and hunting areas" title="Here are your hunting farms and hunting areas in Namibia">Hunting Guides & Farms</a></li>
      </li>  
     </ul>
    </div>`

Comment: Is this what you mean!?

Comment: Yes. In the question, include code relevant to the problem, You will also need to provide CSS that affects the list.

Comment: You close your list item twice

Comment: @allen213 and I was wondering whether or not to correct it while approving the edit in :-)

Comment: #mainrcolIndex ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
#mainrcolIndex ul li {
}
#mainrcolIndex ul a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: li.profmain_location a {
 height: 45px;
 width: 240px;
 float: left;
 background-image: url(../images/profmain_location.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 text-indent: -3000px;
}
li.profmain_location:hover a {
 float: left;
 height: 45px;
 width: 240px;
 background-image: url(../images/profmain_location.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left;
}

Comment: they look the same on my screen. Maybe take a screenshot and show us what you're talking about

Comment: How do I add the image to the comment?

Comment: Try to disable Ghostery or AdBlockPlus, if you want to see the Twitter button also in Firefox and Chrome. Just tested your page in [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and the page is renedered the same as in Explorer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the amount of code you have posted but:

You close your `<li>` twice `</li></li>` this will not help

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the other links to make it shorter, but that is not the problem. I copied the index file of the .de page which displays correctly as a test. When I open it on the .com side, it also displays incorrect.